# In Objective-C, do I need to import every h file to see my object hierarchy?

Tags: objective-c, ios, import

I've created an 3 objects, and chained them together:

- Questionnaire object - which contains a
- NextQuestion object - which contains an
- Answer object - which has an text property.

In a ViewController, I want to be able to call:

```
NSString *thisAnswerText = Questionnaire.nextQuestion.answer.text;
```

However, to do this, I have to import all three files into my .m file

```
#import "Questionnaire.h"
#import "Question.h"
#import "Answer.h"
```

Is it necessary to import each of the objects that I use in each .m file?  Or is there something I can do which means I only need to import the top level item and all it's children are automatically referenced?

NB.  I know that I can add all three to the Prefix.pch file, but I was wondering if I'm missing some trick to Objective-C which allows me to declare one item and it's child objects become imported automatically?

THANK YOU!

Comment: Only import the headers from which you need resources. Although this isn't as inefficient as using `#include` I'd still recommend you only import that you're planning on using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you import a .h file any imports within the .h file are also available. You may need to clean and rebuild but they should be available. So in your case no, you should be able to get away with importing the `Questionaire.h` only.

Also if you're app depends on those custom classes and they will be used all over the place, it can be a good idea to import them in your .pch file and they will be precompiled for all your classes.

Comment: Thanks Ryan!  You nailed it.  If I add one import into each .h file down the chain, I only need to add the first Questionaire.h to be able to see the lot.  You da man Ryan! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it necessary to import each of the objects that I use in each .m file?

Not in all cases, but if you message an object, you should ensure the compiler sees its declaration -- just because ObjC is a very dynamic language.

> Or is there something I can do which means I only need to import the top level item and all it's children are automatically referenced?

Yes, you *could* add an `#import` in any header (of course, the must be compatible with the  translation). However, adding `#import`s should be minimized because `#import`ing the world will increase your build times and introduce a bunch of dependency.

Answer (score 0):

In the public header files for your interfaces, you should forward-declare as much as possible and only `#import` what is really needed. This will help to keep build times down. In your implementation files you can import anything you need.

Sometimes for usability's sake, you may which to collect multiple headers into a single "MyFramework.h" file so that you don't have to add 5 imports everytime you use a class. You should be careful with this however, because it can increase build times if the header is imported in many places.

You may also want to think about adding common imports to your prefix header (.pch) which can be precompiled by Xcode to improve build times a little.